# GDAL/OGR MakeValid seems to be missing from C# bindings

Tags: gdal, gdalogr

Extracting a geometry that is both SQL and ESRI valid with GDAL/OGR using the C# bindings, I get a result from IsValid that conveys that there are ring self intersects. In SQL, if there are intersections, a call to MakeValid will attempt to break a single self-intersecting polygon into multiple non-intersecting valid polygons.  I see that in the C++ and Python API that MakeValid exists for GDAL/OGR, but not for the C# bindings.  Is there just another process to do this, or am I missing it tucked away in another object?

```
 using (var geom = sourceFeature.GetGeometryRef())
    {
        if (!geom.IsValid())
        {
           //attempt to fix invalid geometry
        }
    }
```

Comment: C# bindings are widely used but they are not maintained by the GDAL project like C++ and Python bindings. There may be some differences. If nobody can help you here I suggest to use the contacts from https://gdal.org/api/csharp/index.html.

Comment: You may want tocheck your GDAL and GEOS versions. https://github.com/gisinternals/buildsystem/issues/150

Answer (score 0):

It does appear this is available in the next version of GDAL/OGR C# bindings.  Downloading this has yielded an interesting issue of now flipping polygons lat long values with WGS84 spatial reference, which is less than ideal, but it fixes this problem.  Thanks user2856